# Accessing row in ngTable after it was sorted

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/aHpXIY4pUKziuBOVDoPj?p=preview) I have an `ngTable` with three rows. What I need to know is the row number after it was sorted. For example, sort the `ngTable` by name ascending. You should see in the name column 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc'. Then click on the button, I'm expecting to see the first row updated, however the last row is set with the new values. This happens because the `$scope.data` array itself is not sorted, but `ngTable` sorts a copy internally. I need to update the first "visible" row, how can I achieve that?

HTML

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="u in $data">
                <td title="'User ID'" sortable="'uid'" >
                    {{ u.uid }}
                </td>
                <td title="'Name'" sortable="'nm'" >
                  {{ u.nm }}
                </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {

      $scope.data = [{
          uid: 1,
          nm: 'ccc'
      }, {
          uid: 2,
          nm: 'bbb'
      }, {
          uid: 3,
          nm: 'aaa'
      }];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
          count: 5
      }, {
          data: $scope.data
      });


      $scope.updateRow = function(row){
        $scope.data[row].uid = 999;
        $scope.data[row].nm = 'XXXXX';
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
      };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the data in `tableParams.data`. So to do what you model above, you would just need to do something like this:

```
  $scope.updateRow = function(){
    $scope.tableParams.data[0].uid = 999;
    $scope.tableParams.data[0].nm = 'XXXXX';
    $scope.data = $scope.tableParams.data;
  };
```

Comment: this seems to work fine to update the row, but doesn't work when adding a row with `$scope.tableParams.data.push(row)` or when deleting a row with `$scope.tableParams.data.splice(rowNumber, 1);`

Comment: If you want to remove a row, you could add a remove button to each row you create and call a function on the controller passing `$index` as a parameter.